# How to use angular flex layout with inline-styles disabled?

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, angular-flex-layout

I am using "'self'" content security policy for style src. It doesn't allow inline styles. Angular Flex layout adds inline styles. Is there a way to solve this problem ? I don't want to use hashes or nonce because it would be a lot of work.

Comment: You will also have to use `unsafe-inline` along with `self`

Comment: I am using ZAP for vulnerability and penetration testing. Setting unsafe-inline shows as a vulnerability.

Comment: Use ngCSP directive: [<body ng-csp="no-inline-style">](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)

Comment: @granty sorry I didn't mention that I was using Angular 9.

Comment: Looks like that's impossible without using nonces - Suggested Steps: 1. [We should clearly state that allowing 'unsafe-inline' in style-src is required for Angular applications](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37631)